# How to find if a method of a particular prototype exists inside a class?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, sfinae

I'm working with some SFINAE features; currently in a portion of an application that must run in Linux and Windows; the compiler choices are MSVC (Visual Studio 2010 10.0) for Windows applications and GCC 4.4.5 for the Linux ones.

I must check if some given object provides some functions to perform a custom serialization and call this functions, or do a simple `memcpy` and `sizeof(Object)` while the custom serialization methods are not provided.

The problem is that a piece of code compile without warnings nor errors in MSVC but while compiling with GCC, the code is the following:

```
template
    <
        typename Type,
        typename Return,
        typename Parameter,
        Return (Type::*Pointer)(Parameter) const
    > struct sMemberMethodConst { };

template
    <
        typename Type,
        typename Return,
        typename Parameter,
        Return (Type::*)(Parameter)
    > struct sMemberMethod { };

template<typename T> struct sMemberMethodChecker
{
    template <typename Type> static char HasCustomSizeMethod(sMemberMethodConst<Type, size_t, void, &Type::Size> *);
    template <typename Type> static long HasCustomSizeMethod(...);
    template <typename Type> static char HasSerializeMethod(sMemberMethodConst<Type, size_t, void * const, &Type::Serialize> *);
    template <typename Type> static long HasSerializeMethod(...);
    template <typename Type> static char HasDeserializeMethod(sMemberMethod<Type, size_t, const void * const, &Type::Deserialize> *);
    template <typename Type> static long HasDeserializeMethod(...);
    // Other specific method checks...

    enum
    {
        HAS_CUSTOM_SIZE_METHOD =    (sizeof(HasCustomSizeMethod<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)),
        HAS_SERIALIZE_METHOD =      (sizeof(HasSerializeMethod<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)),
        HAS_DESERIALIZE_METHOD =    (sizeof(HasDeserializeMethod<T>(0)) == sizeof(char)),
        IS_CUSTOM =                 HAS_CUSTOM_SIZE_METHOD &&
                                    HAS_SERIALIZE_METHOD &&
                                    HAS_DESERIALIZE_METHOD,
        // Other 'shortcuts'...
    };
```

And the error that I'm getting while compiling with GCC is:

`invalid parameter type 'void' in declaration template<class Type, class Return, class Parameter, Return (Type::* Pointer)(Parameter)const>`

in the first line of the `struct sMemberMethodChecker`. I'm quite sure that I'm don't missing `typename`s nor misplacing words but I don't understand why I'm getting the error and doesn't understand the error.

I know that the MSVC is lax with standard while GCC conforms the standard pretty well so I'm wondering if the problem lies into the MSVC side that allows *silly code*!

Here are the questions:

- Why am I getting the `invalid parameter type 'void'` error in the `struct sMemberMethodChecker`?.
- Why the code is valid in MSVC but invalid in GCC?.
- Is this code non-standard?.
- Is the SFINAE trickery exclusive of C++11?

Comment: Is `const void * const` allowed? You are telling the compiler that you have a `const void` type of object. But voids can't be modified anyway AFAIK? What happens if you try `void * const`?

Comment: Good question. It seems that GCC is not accepting `template
    <
        typename Type,
        typename Return,
        typename Parameter,
        Return (Type::*)(` **void** `)
    > struct sMemberMethod { };` as parameter. Whereas, MSVC is being liberal about it.

Comment: I believe iammilind is right. Unlike C, C++ does not allow `void` in a function's argument list. That's because in C, `f()` is a function without a prototype (= parameters unspecified), while in C++, `f()` is a function with no arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I'm getting the invalid parameter type 'void' error in the struct
>   sMemberMethodChecker?.
>
> Why the code is valid in MSVC but it isn't in GCC?.

I believe that MSVC is being helpful however GCC is being stringent in this particular code. As it's somehow not allowing `Return (Type::*)(void)`. However one need to dig it more to know the exact reason.

> Is this code no-standard?.

Can't say until it doesn't compile. And searching standard for the features like SFINAE is not everyone's cup of tea.

> Is the SFINAE trickery exclusive of C++11?

Not at all. SFINAE existed before C++11.
Here is the **simplified** way of what you want to do:

```
template<typename ClassName, typename ClassMethodType>
struct HasMethod
{
  template<typename Type, Type Object> struct Contains;
  typedef char (&yes)[2];

  template<typename Class, typename MethodType>
  static yes Check (Contains<MethodType, &Class::size>*);
  template<typename Class, typename MethodType>
  static char Check (...);

  static const bool value = (sizeof(Check<ClassName,ClassMethodType>(0)) == sizeof(char));
};
```

`HasMethod<ClassName, ClassMethodType>::value` gives you the answer if a certain type member method exists inside it or not.
As of now `HasMethod<>` is exclusive to the *method naming* `size` with user provided type. But you can create a macro for above code and make the *function name configurable*.

Here is a [working demo with g++](http://ideone.com/8W5wdT).

Comment: Very good answers! unfortunately the example code doesn't suits exactly what I need but guided me to solve the main problem pretty well, btw: thanks for correcting my poor english ;)